# Python delete value by destroying reference to it

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a complex data structure (multidimensional dict with lists of tuples) which is filtered by multiple functions and finally returns a list or dictionary of deletable objects, something similar to this:

```
import sys

d1 = {'a': 1, 'd': 3, 'f': 4, 'g': 5, 'h': 6, 'j': 7, 'k': 8, 'l': 9, 's': 2}
d2 = {1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f', 5: 'g', 6: 'h', 7: 'j', 8: 'k', 9: 'l'}

def filter1(d1, d2):
    dd1 = {k:v for k,v in d1.items() if k not in ['a','l']}
    dd2 = {k:v for k,v in d2.items() if k not in [4, 6]}
    return dict(dd1.items() + dd2.items())

def filter2(d):
    return {k:v for k,v in d.items() if not isinstance(v, int) if 3 < k < 8}

f = filter2(filter1(d1,d2))
```

By looking at the reference count it seems that these objects point to the same values. Further their ids are exactly the same.

```
In [2]: sys.getrefcount(f[5])
Out[2]: 15

In [3]: sys.getrefcount(d2[5])
Out[3]: 15

In [4]: 

In [4]: test = d2[5]

In [5]: 

In [5]: sys.getrefcount(f[5])
Out[5]: 16

In [6]: sys.getrefcount(d2[5])
Out[6]: 16

In [7]: 

In [7]: id(f[5])
Out[7]: 140313621257992

In [8]: id(d2[5])
Out[8]: 140313621257992
```

After filtering in the final product I essentially get a dict of references. Deleting objects from that dict should automagically remove original attributes from either `d1`, `d2`.

I wonder if it is possible to delete these objects by id, or somehow destroy references to their values and let garbage collector do the job?

Otherwise my filter functions must keep track of which `dict[key]` and from which `list[index]` each object has been taken and then delete explicitly. This is quite difficult and error prone job...

Desired output:

```
for v in f.values():
    del v

d2 = {1: 'a', 2: 's', 3: 'd', 4: 'f', 6: 'h', 8: 'k', 9: 'l'}
```

Comment: Of course the values in the dictionaries are references to the same objects. That's entirely normal. No, you cannot use `id()` values to delete references, and you don't *need* to. Your 'desired output' creates a *new* reference (`v`), which you then destroy again with `del v`.

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me what you mean by a *returns a list or dictionary of deletable objects*? The filters do not retain any references to the objects , so there is no need to worry about deletions there. If you wanted to remove items from `d1` or `d2`, then you produce a list of keys and delete the keys from the original dictionary.

Comment: How is that unclear what I'm asking?? Like I've showed after some filtering I get a list (a dict in my example) with objects which are references to some other object's attributes. I would like to reuse this list (dict in my example) for deleting/removing original attributes in the original object (key/value pairs in my dict d2).

Comment: So you want your final list or dict (produced from the filter) to be a live view on the original object; if you delete items from the original `d1` or `d2` the filtered output should update too?

Comment: No, I get a dict of references after filtering in my final product. Deleting objects from that dict should automagically remove original object from either d1, d2.

Comment: That's not how Python works, no. You return a list of keys, then delete those keys explicitly.

Comment: Since now it's clear what I was asking, could you remove "on hold" tag?

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to add that clarification?

Comment: Seems like you are having concerns and using terminology borrowed from a different language (C, C++).

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use the `id()` of an object to delete references to the object. You'll have to delete the correct keys from `d1` and `d2` to remove those references.

Have your filter return a *set* of keys that need deleting from those dictionaries, then loop over the set and explicitly remove those:

```
for key in filter2(filter1(d1,d2)):
    d1.pop(key, None)
    d2.pop(key, None)
```

I used `dict.pop()` to allow for the key to be missing.

Answer (score 0):

I could not directly adapt your example with it, but IMHO the closest Python tool to your requirement is *weak references*.

A weak reference can reference an object as long as it exists, but when the last *hard reference* to it disappears, the object is no longer valid and can be garbage collected. When you try to get a reference to a no longer alive object, you just get None.

So if you want that removing objects in a *reference* dict removes it from the original dict, you have to replace the object in the original dict with a weak reference to the object in the ref dict. That way, when you remove the object from the other dict, the weak ref is not enough to keep the object alive and it disappears.

But as I said in the beginning, I could not adapt this to your example, because you construct you filtered lists by keeping good values, when the weakref would require you to first put everythin in filtered list and then delete what you do not want to keep.